# svjour3 | smartqed symbol issue

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing a math paper for a Springer journal, using the `svjour3` class. According to the manual, `\smartqed` should produce a right justified K symbol, but it does not. On the other hand, `\qed` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
If $X$, then $Y$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Clear. \smartqed
\end{proof}
\begin{theorem}
If $X$, then $Y$.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
Clear. \qed
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

The directory contains `svjour3.cls`, `svglov3.clo`, `spmpsci.bst`, and the file `s.tex` containing the above code. I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and compile with PDFLaTeX. The files are available at: http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/LaTeX.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-468198-0

Answer (score 8):

The `\smartqed` macro just redefines `\qed`. Put the former in the preamble of your document and use the latter as usual.

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\smartqed

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}
    If $X$, then $Y$.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    Clear. \qed
  \end{proof}
  \begin{theorem}
    If $X$, then $Y$.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{proof}
    Clear. \qed
  \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Thorsten. Your answer has saved me a lot of time. As is frequently the case, the code is fine, but the explanation in the manual leaves something to be desired.